# How to indent the whole text and float environment?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

Using http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=251&start=10
I can  indent the text, but   how  to center  the  figures  and  table  like the image  as follow?

[image]

My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[a4paper,text={150true mm,224true mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}                % define section style
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\leftskip=6em \oldsection}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\leftskip=6em \oldsubsection}
\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\leftskip=6em \oldsubsubsection}
\begin{document}
\section{First section} 
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\rule{4cm}{2cm}
\caption{figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection} 
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Second subsection} 
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Third subsection} 
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Last subsection} 
\lipsum[5]
\section{Second section} 
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First subsection} 
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Second subsection} 
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Third subsection} 
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

get

[image]

Comment: Apply `\centering` within the `figure` environment should do the trick.  If not, please post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your figures are `centered` with respect to `text width` (not text). I suggest a different approach. To get the desired effect you may increase the left margin and push the sections etc into the left margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
%\usepackage[a4paper,text width=110true mm,text height=224true mm]{geometry} % or
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,height rounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{8em}
\usepackage{titlesec}                % define section style
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\hspace*{-5em}\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace*{-6em}\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\hspace*{-6em}\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\section{First section} 
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\rule{4cm}{2cm}
\caption{figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection} 
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Second subsection} 
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Third subsection} 
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Last subsection} 
\lipsum[5]
\section{Second section} 
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First subsection} 
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Second subsection} 
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Third subsection} 
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to use a `\parbox` within your figure environment. I've also made use of the [`calc`](http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf) package,

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hfill\parbox{\textwidth - 6em}{%
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{2cm}
    \caption{figure}\label{fig:1}%
}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Complete Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[a4paper,text={150true mm,224true mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}               % define section style
\usepackage{calc}                   % basic arithmetic operations
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\leftskip=6em \oldsection}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\leftskip=6em \oldsubsection}
\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\leftskip=6em \oldsubsubsection}
\begin{document}
\section{First section} 
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hfill\parbox{\textwidth - 6em}{%
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{2cm}
    \caption{figure}\label{fig:1}%
}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection} 
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Second subsection} 
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Third subsection} 
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Last subsection} 
\lipsum[5]
\section{Second section} 
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First subsection} 
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Second subsection} 
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Third subsection} 
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: we must change it  every float enviornment

Comment: Indeed. If you plan on reusing the code, you could define a new control sequence with `\newcommand`. However, this may be bad practice. @Harish Kumar's solution would be what you are looking for.